# Why is the adjective for "mutate" not "mutatable"?

Tags: adjectives, etymology, word-form

The adjective for "mutate" is "mutable", and not "mutatable". I wonder why the last two letters (-te) have been removed before adding "-able" to the end of it. Is there any rule? Any similar adjectives?

Comment: Note that even for native English speakers, it's quite easy to say "mutatable" by accident -- it might be wrong, but it's very understandable.

Answer (score 34):

Good question.  The reason has to do with the fact that the verb **mutate** was a *back-formation* from the noun **mutation**.  That is, the English noun *mutation* existed first, and the verb *mutate* was invented later to match it.

Both came ultimately from the Latin *mutare* (to change form) and *mutatio* (a change).

I'm not sure, but the "correct" way to do this might have been to create the verb **mute**.

Unfortunately, **mute** (myoot) already existed in English, meaning "silent"(adj) / "to silence" (v). It has a separate derivation:

Latin — mutis

Old French — mu

French — muet

English —mute
http://i.word.com/idictionary/mute

And **moot** also already existed in English, with quite a distinct meaning (related to "meet") from Germanic origins. 
http://i.word.com/idictionary/moot

So it seems the solution taken was to adopt the Latin-sounding **mutate** as the verb form, to avoid confusion with **moot** or **mute**.

But **mutable** came fairly directly from Latin *mutabilis*.  (This did not collide with existing English, because apparently **mutable**, in the sense of *silenceable*, did not exist in English  (or if it ever did, that meaning disappeared long ago; it is not listed in, for instance, Merriam-Webster—not even as archaic.))  http://i.word.com/idictionary/mutable

Comment: Interesting. Now that audio equipment/software actually have a "mute" button people are actually starting to use "mutable" to mean silenceable. At least in user manuals and datasheets.

Comment: @slebetman - I write it "muteable", which is actually a word according to Wiktionary meaning "Capable of being muted."

Comment: That makes sense.  And i have noticed "sizeable" (i.e. resizeable; e.g. a window of a PC app) spelled differently from "sizable" (large). But sometimes they spell it the same.

Answer (score 21):

There are a bunch of rules how adjectives ending with -able are formed. And yes, one of them is that *silent '**e**'s are dropped*, which would support your expectation of *mutate -> mutatable*.

However, there is another rule that deals with verbs ending with **-ate**:

> Traditionally, verbs ending in -ate **drop this suffix** before adding -able; hence,
>
> - communicable (“able to be communicated”),
> - eradicable (“possible to eradicate”),
> - implacable (“unable to be placated”),
> - inimitable (“unable to imitated”), and so on,
> - but relatable, because relate is re- + -late, not rel- + -ate.
>
> Logically one should therefore say rotable to mean "able to be rotated", but rotatable has become accepted.

<sup>(Source: [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-able))</sup>

Your *mutable* falls squarely in this category.

Answer (score 3):

The adjective existed already in Latin mutabilis/mutabile, from the verb mutare. So English mutable is not derived from English to mutate, but has the original Latin form.

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=mutable&searchmode=none

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, there is no general rule for forming adjectives.
However, when you use the suffix able to form adjectives from the verbs that end with "tate", you usually omit the last three letters "ate" and use the suffix "able".

Some examples are as follows:

Agtitate - agitable

Irritate - irritable

Imitate - imitable

mutate - mutable